# v-for delay dom patching when data update

Tags: vue.js

I'm noticing that the `v-for` I'm using to render some images inside a component, when data are updated using the event bus,I will have a little delay in DOM content replacing. Is there a way to solve this little problem?

**NB:** I can't replicate the data passed because it's a 50 elements list of images urls and are provided by an external api service.

```
<template>
    <div class="row m-0 pl-5 pr-5">

        <div class="col-4 col-img hide p-0" v-for="(img, idx) in feed" :key="idx" v-observe-visibility="visibilityChanged">
            <img class="img-fluid w-100 h-100 ig-image" :src="img.url">
            <div class="card-img-overlay text-center">
                <p class="text-white">{{ img.likes }} <i class="fas fa-heart"></i> {{ img.comments }} <i class="fas fa-comment"></i></p>
            </div>
            <a class="stretched-link" href="#image-modal" data-toggle="modal" v-on:click.prevent="zoomImage(img.url)"></a>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { EventBus } from '@/standalone/event-bus'

export default {
    name: 'UserMedia',
    data() {
        return {
            feed: null,
            imgUrl: null
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        EventBus.$on('profile-media', (media) => {
            this.$set(this, 'feed', media)     
        })
    },
    methods: {
        zoomImage(url) {
            this.$set(this, 'imgUrl', url)
        },
        visibilityChanged(isVisible, el) {
            if(isVisible){
                el.target.classList.remove('hide')
                el.target.classList.add('show')
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.col-img {
    height: 420px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example/fiddle?

Comment: @MajedBadawi see the updated question. The feed is an object of 50 images

Comment: This does not show your problem. Please provide a sample case with the data.

Comment: the data are provided by an api service and are images urls, I'm unable to replicate them in the question

Answer (score 1):

Since if you change the data 'feed', it will take time to load the images but inorder to load small size images prior to heavy size for good user experience you can use some very good npm packages:

- npm i vue-lazyload (I have used it and recommend this one)
- npm i v-lazy-image (I haven't used yet but you can explore this as well)

Comment: ok, so you think the problem is because the images time loading?I will try to lazy load them

Comment: Tested, but the problem still remain. when the `feed` var is updated and all the old data are replaced I continue see the old images for a while also with lazy load